# Calculated range in criteria range in SUMIFS

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I'm trying to use calculated array in SUMIFS criteria range; basically, not a standard column of cells.

I don't wish to add another helper column.

```
SUMIFS(J$5:J$124,($J$4-J$5:J$124)/365,"<"&I128)
```

- Here J$4 is the current month.
- J$%:J$124 are the opening dates.

Comment: May you show the data from J4 to J124?

Comment: 6.1
0.5
1.9
-
-
-
1.1
-
4.7
4.7
-
-
1.4
-
-
3.0
-
-
-
-
-
-
1.8
-
0.5
-
-
-
1.7
-
-
0.7
-
-
-
-
0.3
-
1.2
0.8
0.1
-
-
0.4
-
-
-
-
-
-
-
-
-
0.2
-
-
-
-
-
0.8
1.3
1.0
-
-
-
1.6
-
-
-
-
1.3
0.4
-
4.0
0.5
0.2
-
3.3
-
0.4
-
-
-
-
2.4
3.7
1.3
-
0.5
-
0.9
-
-
-
-
-
1.8
0.8
-
1.1
0.4
1.1
0.3
1.0
-
-
1.1
-
-
-
-
-
-
-
2.1
-
5.0
-
4.9
1.6

Answer (score 0):

You should exclude the calculations from the criteria range and do them outside of it. Try the following:

```
SUMIFS(J$5:J$124,J$5:J$124,">"&J4-I128*365)
```